# Multiple XIBs embeded in UIStackViews displayed in one StoryBoard with UIStackViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib, uistackview

I am using multiple XIBs/Storyboards to build my application.

I have the views laid out in the XIBs. Some have `UIStackView` to help organize the layout.

My main storyboard has two views embedded in a `UIStackView` that pulls in those views that are created with the `XIBs`.

**Nothing will display correctly.** The views are mis-sized or do not show up at all, despite displaying properly in interface builder.

My suspicion is the views are being displayed, *BEFORE* they are fully loaded into the view causing the frames to be different sizes.

I've been told the best practice is to give views their own Storyboard/XIB for better merging, maintenance etc... So that is what I am trying to learn.

Does anyone know the proper way to accomplish what I am doing?

Here is what I am doing:

**ViewController**

```
#import "OrangeView.h"
#import "GreenView.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    OrangeView *ov;
    GreenView *gv;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewOrange;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewGreen;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Load Orange View
    ov = [[OrangeView alloc] initWithFrame:_viewOrange.frame];
    [_viewOrange addSubview:ov];

    //Load GreenView
    gv = [[GreenView alloc] initWithFrame:_viewGreen.frame];
    [_viewGreen addSubview:gv];

}
```

**Main Storyboard**

[image]

**OrangeView**

[image]

**GreenView (with multiple stackviews)**

[image]

**Overview**

[image]

Comment: Using separate Storyboards / xib files *can* be helpful, depending on the complexity of your app. Sometimes, they can be more trouble than they are worth. If you want to load views + subviews from a xib, you have to do more than simply instantiate the class. What is your ultimate goal here? Do you want your xib views to load and *scale* to fit specified frames? Do you want to load xib views and have their "internal" frames / constraints determine their sizes?

Comment: The former. I would like the subviews to scale to fit the specified frames.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a `.xib` file are not "linked" to the class. That is, when you instantiate the class, that does not - by itself - also load the views and subviews you've laid out in the xib.

There are a couple ways to go about it. One method is to include the "load the elements" code inside your view class. That allows a more "conventional" approach of load/create a view instance, add as subview, set parameters (frame or constraints), etc.

Here is an example of subclassing `UIView` with the "xib-load" functions, and then making your actual class a sub-class of this "base":

---

```
//
//  XIBViewBase.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XIBViewBase : UIView

@end
```

---

```
//
//  XIBViewBase.m
//

#import "XIBViewBase.h"

@implementation XIBViewBase

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        [self xibSetup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

    if (self) {
        [self xibSetup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self xibSetup];
}

- (void)xibSetup {

    // make sure we don't add the subviews more than once
    if (!self.subviews.count) {

        UIView *view = [self loadFromXIB];

        view.frame = self.bounds;
        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [self addSubview:view];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:view];

    }

}

- (UIView *)loadFromXIB {

    // Note: the .xib file MUST be named the same as the class for this to work

    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:className bundle:bundle];
    UIView *v = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil].firstObject;

    return v;

}

@end
```

---

I put together an example of this (using your target) that you can take a look at. Might help you get a handle on it:

https://github.com/DonMag/SimpleXIB

---